# deep copy of StyleFrame object

Tags: python, copy, styleframe

How can I make a shallow or deep copy of StyleFrame object?
When I use copy.copy(sf) or , copy.deepcopy(sf) I get error:
"RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object"

```
import copy
from StyleFrame import StyleFrame
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame([list('abc')])
sf=StyleFrame(df)
copy.copy(sf)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\python\python373\lib\copy.py", line 106, in copy
    return _reconstruct(x, None, *rv)
  File "C:\python\python373\lib\copy.py", line 281, in _reconstruct
    if hasattr(y, '__setstate__'):
  File "C:\python\python373_vm1\lib\site-packages\StyleFrame\style_frame.py", line 121, in __getattr__
    if attr in self.data_df.columns:
  File "C:\python\python373_vm1\lib\site-packages\StyleFrame\style_frame.py", line 121, in __getattr__
    if attr in self.data_df.columns:
  File "C:\python\python373_vm1\lib\site-packages\StyleFrame\style_frame.py", line 121, in __getattr__
    if attr in self.data_df.columns:
  [Previous line repeated 495 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass the original StyleFrame object to `StyleFrame`. Internally it will deep copy the underlying dataframe and will also copy some internal attributes.

```
sf = StyleFrame({'a': [1, 2]})
print(id(sf))
new_sf = StyleFrame(sf)
print(id(new_sf))
```

Outputs

```
1971232017152
1971267198144
```

Comment: I was bit worried about internal attributes while directly deepcopying the data_df.  But Instantiating StyleFrame with existing styleframe object removes that concern.

Comment: The StyleFrame(sf) seems to works generally but it for throws an error in below case:
`sf=StyleFrame.read_excel(r'C:\temp\test.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', read_style=True, use_openpyxl_styles=True)`
`sf2=StyleFrame(sf)`
`sf3=StyleFrame(sf2)`

`TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'worksheet'`
`